# Doubts about inner product operation of function.

Tags: inner-products

For a heat conduction equation：
$$ \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}-\Delta \varphi=0. $$
Take the inner product of both sides of this equation with ($ -\Delta \varphi $ ), how can I get：
$$ \frac12\frac{d}{dt}\langle \nabla\varphi,\nabla\varphi\rangle + \Vert \Delta\varphi\Vert^2=0. \tag{1}$$
My main problem is the first term on the LHS of the equation (1).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The inner product is defined by :

\begin{align}
\langle f,g\rangle = \int f^* g\;\text dx
\end{align}

Therefore, integration by part gives : $\langle \nabla f,g\rangle = -\langle f,\nabla g \rangle$.

From this, you have :
\begin{align}
\frac 12 \frac{\text d}{\text dt}\langle \nabla \varphi,\nabla\varphi\rangle &= \left\langle \nabla \varphi,\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla\varphi\right\rangle \\
&=\left\langle \nabla \varphi,\nabla\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}\right\rangle \\
&=-\left\langle \Delta\varphi,\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}\right\rangle\\
&=-\langle \Delta\varphi,\Delta\varphi\rangle\\
&=- \|\Delta\varphi\|^2
\end{align}

Comment: $\langle \nabla f,g\rangle=-\langle f,\nabla g\rangle$ not $+\langle f,\nabla g\rangle$.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for pointing this out !